# How to find if a list is sub string of a string in a Data Frame column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am facing a challenge to find a substring from a list inside a DataFrame column

```
list =['ab', 'bc', 'ca']

DF1
Index|A
0    |ajbijio_ab_jadds
1    |bhjbj_ab_jiui

Expected OUTPUT:
DF
ab
ab
```

I have written something but it is giving error
unhashable type: 'list'

```
DF1['A'].str.lower().str.contains(list)
```

Comment: what output you want if there are multiple matches from the list?

Comment: You say substring, but can it be a substring of **any** part of the string, or are you looking for exact matches to an entire substring separated by `_`? Would `'bh'` be considered a match for the second row?

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.extract`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

lst =['ab','bc','ca']

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["ajbijio_ab_jadds", "bhjbj_ab_jiui", "Hello World"]})
df["Found"] = df["A"].str.extract("(" + "|".join(lst) + ")")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                  A Found
0  ajbijio_ab_jadds    ab
1     bhjbj_ab_jiui    ab
2       Hello World   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) if need first match only with `join` list by `|` for regex `OR`:

```
L =['ab','bc','ca']

df['new'] = df['A'].str.extract('('+ '|'.join(L) + ')')
print (df)
                  A new
0  ajbijio_ab_jadds  ab
1     bhjbj_ab_jiui  ab
```

If need all matches use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['new'] = df['A'].str.findall('|'.join(L)).str.join(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using `findall`

```
df["Found"] = df["A"].str.findall("|".join(lst)).str[0]

df
Out[82]: 
                  A Found
0  ajbijio_ab_jadds    ab
1     bhjbj_ab_jiui    ab
2       Hello World   NaN
```